# LINQ get particular rows from in array

Tags: c#, linq

I joined two datatables & trying to get the results in the array.

```
dt
ID   A    B    C
1    ab   t    j
2    cd   h    k
3    ds   f    g

ndt
CID     E    F   G
1       g    y   gg
2       ff   hg  vcb
3       df   vb   b
```

Code

```
var query = from r0w1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join r0w2 in ndt.AsEnumerable()
                 on r0w1.Field<string>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<string>("CID")
                 select r0w2.ItemArray.Concat(r0w1.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

What I want here is no to select the column `CID` from above result since both the columns `ID` & `CID` are same. How can I avoid it ?

Comment: can u show sample data inputs and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `CID` always goes first in your row, you can utilize LINQ `Skip` to skip the first item:

```
var query = from r0w1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join r0w2 in ndt.AsEnumerable()
            on r0w1.Field<string>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<string>("CID")
            select r0w2.ItemArray.Skip(1).Concat(r0w1.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was writing mistake, but that was not the actual problem.

Comment: This answer should work provided that "CID" is first column as shown in output.